# Windows Remote Desktop: Different configurations based on location

Tags: windows, group-policy, remote-desktop, rdp

Is it possible to set up remote desktop (via group policy or another method) so that it has different settings based on where the user is connecting to the session from?

In my scenario, I'd like to have a user able to access local drives and clipboard while connecting from a domain PC but to deny these rights when that same user is connecting via there laptop on a different (home or other) network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are client-side settings, so there's no way to control them for non-domain computers.